# How to subset a large data set with multiple conditions?

Tags: r

My full data set is larger but I have this reproducible sample:

```
structure(list(ID = c("121", "122", "123", "124"), Var1P = c("3", 
"1", "3", "3"), Var1C = c("1", "3", "3", "1"), Var2P = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1"), Var2P = c("1", "1", "1", "1"), Var3P = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1"), Var3C = c("1", "1", "1", "1"), Var4P = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1"), Var4C = c("1", "3", "1", "1"), Var5P = c("1", 
"1", "3", "1"), Var5C = c("1", "1", "1", "1"), Var6P = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1"), Var6C = c("1", "1", "1", "1"), Var7P = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1"), Var7C = c("1", "1", "1", "1"), Var8 = c("0", 
"1", "1", "1")), row.names = c(84L, 150L, 271L, 303L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to subset the data so that only the observations with a score of 3 under Var1P or Var1C and all other columns a score of 2, 1, or 0. I have tried to use the simple subset function:

```
Data <- subset(Data, Var1P == 3 | Var1C == 3)
```

But, how can I make this argument even more complex to also tell R to also remove entries with scores of 3 under the other columns?

I thought simply using the following code would work:

```
Data <- subset(Data, Var1P == 3 | Var1C == 3 & 4:16 == 1 | 4:16 == 0)
```

It doesn't because R would then be looking at the row numbers, I think. I don't want to type out all of the column names because like I said my full data frame is much larger. I also am trying to avoid loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can divide the data into two sets of columns, `select_cols` are the columns where you want to select rows with 3 in them and `remove_cols` are the remaining columns.

We can then select rows with `rowSums` where `select_cols` has 3 in it but `remove_cols` doesn't.

```
select_cols <- c('Var1P', 'Var1C')
remove_cols <- setdiff(names(Data), select_cols)
Data[rowSums(Data[select_cols] == 3) > 0 & rowSums(Data[remove_cols] == 3) == 0, ]

#     ID Var1P Var1C Var2P Var2P Var3P Var3C Var4P Var4C Var5P Var5C Var6P Var6C Var7P Var7C Var8
#84  121     3     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1    0
#303 124     3     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1    1
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm thinking of this correctly, the ```rowSums(Data[remove_cols] == 3) == 0,]``` is still keeping the scores of 1 why, exactly? It's not literally telling R to keep data equal to 0, right? Your method worked perfectly so I'm just trying to understand it better.

Comment: `rowSums(Data[remove_cols] == 3) == 0,]` is telling R to select rows where there are no 3 values in `remove_cols`. So this ensures that there are no 3 values anything except 3 can exist.